# How to fix a menu on top right of the visible portion of the web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I have a web page that is not responsive except the navigation menu, which is made to be tablet and mobile friendly.

When i load the page on the phone, this one is not completely visible horizontally (60% of the the width is visible let's say), which is fine at this point of the project. But still i want to have the mobile menu always placed on the top right of the visible portion of the page.

Right now the menu is placed top right relatively to the complete width of the page.

How to realize this easily ? ( Jquery or simply CSS )

Thanks!

Comment: Without code we're just guessing, but it sounds like the navigation is positioned to the window, and not to container you would like, the one that is visible. It might be as simple as moving the nav code somewhere else in the HTML.

Comment: My container has a fixed 1024px as width. Phone has 490px as width let's say. When i load the page in the phone, only the half of it is visible horizontely, which is ok for me, except that the nav is not visible cause it is placed completely on the top right of the 1024px width. I want it to be placed in the top right of the 490px ( which is the visible portion of the page)

Comment: So if you knew where it needed to be since it's being cut off, why not use a media query to push the nav over depending on that value?

Comment: Do you want navbar 100% of the width?  I made a codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WbRVBR

Comment: I don't know exactly, cause the width differs from a media to another...

Comment: i'll check your solution and come back to you

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like

`#some_div { position: fixed; right: 0px; top: 0px;}`

?

Comment: This one will place the menu on top right of the web page. If only 60% of the page is visible, then the menu will not be visible. The idea is to be able to show the menu on the visible portion of the page, no matter what media is used ( phone, desktop, tablet...)